# what's the shortcut for copying cursor's current line?

Tags: matlab, keyboard-shortcuts

what's the shortcut for copying cursor's current line?
In matlab's preference setting, I can't find it in the the shortcut key panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select the current line and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

For selecting the line, press <kbd>Home</kbd> button to take the cursor to the beginning of line and then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> to select the line to its end. These steps work in multiple applications; not just MATLAB.

A line can also be selected with triple mouse click on the line or clicking the space between the break-point gutter and the start of the line (cursor horizontally flips to [image: inverted-cursor] in this space).

Relevant Mathworks blog: [Selecting a whole line](https://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2010/05/03/selecting-a-whole-line/)

Comment: for mac, cmd+ left to cursor to the begining, then cmd + shift + right select to the end